# how to add pagination on custom collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, custom, pagination

I am working on custom module. How can i use default magento **pagination** with my **custom collection** and also set custom limits on that?

Comment: When i created my custom module in magento2 for pagination & limits i referred these link (http://www.mage-world.com/blog/create-the-news-list-page-via-frontend-in-magento-2.html) and i could get it done.

Comment: Could you please explain on how to override the Magento Catalog for adding pagination to custom module!  the above link i got some idea, i want to override in Catalog module

Comment: @SachinS i thin you are talking about toolbar?

Comment: Yes exactly...I have described what i tried and error here...http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131896/add-pagination-in-custom-module-magento-2

Comment: @SachinS what you want achieve with toolbar and did you solve this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131805/how-to-use-settemplate-in-custom-modules-construct-magento2/131812

Comment: I want to get the pager and sorter controls when i click on Catalog categories link in frontpage which i have overridden, but i tried above way, i get only those controls

Comment: See the updated answer, where there are no pager and sorter controls

Comment: Follow this link : https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-add-pagination-to-custom-collection-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

get collection for that

```
public function getNews()
    {
      //get values of current page
        $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    //get values of current limit
        $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 1;


        $newsCollection = $this->newscollectionFactory->create();
        $newsCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);
        $newsCollection->setOrder('title','ASC');
        $newsCollection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $newsCollection->setCurPage($page);
        return $newsCollection;
    }
```

Add pagination

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('News'));


    if ($this->getNews()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'test.news.pager'
        )->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15))->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
            $this->getNews()
        );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getNews()->load();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

adding the child block

```
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}
```

in phtml file

```
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

[Reference](http://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-add-pagination-custom-collection/)

Comment: Pssst: either `$this->getRequest()->getParam('p') ?: 1` or, better yet, `$this->getRequest()->getParam('p', 1)`.

Comment: I get element with id already exists error for whatever I try to name the pager block I'm creating using your code.

Comment: @LM_Fielding not faced this issue yet but try deleting `var/cache` and `var/generation` folder

Comment: I was trying to add it for a toolbar at the top and at the bottom, so it was exactly correct.

Comment: @LM_Fielding you are adding it twice that is causing the problem.

Comment: Indeed. But it confused me because I was only using one block. So you can only use the block with that once in any layout unless you passed an argument to modify the block id, such as "top" or "bottom" as location.

Comment: @QaisarSatti , am creating block same as in your template file and also same as block but in page , it is not as default pager why ? and  what I need to do ?

Comment: @supriyamishra i check your code you are using toolbar this in only pager

Comment: @QaisarSatti my pager count is not aligned with show per page as it is on category pages. <div class="toolbar bottom">
                <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
               <div class="toolbar-amount"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div> 
            <?php endif;?>
             </div>   plz help

Comment: @supriyamishra you are adding custom limit to that? i give you answer about that add available limit same as your limit then they will work

Comment: Am giving config limit which can be set from admin, else it was not showing  all products. when I added available limit it was coming on page 1 , 1-1 of 62, and on page 2 , 37-37 of 62 only single products in each page.

Comment: did you using this code 
 
`/get values of current page
        $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    //get values of current limit
        $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 1;`
also `$newsCollection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $newsCollection->setCurPage($page);`

Comment: Thank  you very much satti u r solution has been worked for me good job bro.

Comment: What to replace in place of fme.news.pager?

Comment: perfect answer with reference link!!! +1 :) made my day

Comment: I use this same code . 
Items are limited show as we define But below `tolbar` is not show for next page

Comment: @hafizumer check with inspect elements and check

Comment: Sir this is error in console 

http://domain.com/pub/media/styles.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Comment: this error also show in all pages where magento2 defualt pagination work .

Comment: Aoa ! Ramadan Mubarak Sir.
 i try to apply pagination on custom product page collection. 
i use the same template of magento catalog module  for show the products  view->frontend->template->product->list.phtml.

Products render on page correctly and limited product shown on page But tolbar is not show. 

I think am doing mistake in .phtml file

Comment: @hafizumer w salam ramadan mubarik. This answer for pagination not toolbar.

Comment: which toolbar Sir ? i mean to say next page show numbering .  Sir please see this screenshot 

https://screenshots.firefox.com/gsZ3QEwpVxOXZWkx/localhost

Comment: Sir 
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'test.news.pager'

Sir i don't change the `test.news.pager` in creatBlock parameter. 
due to this is not show next page numbering pagination ? 
whats the replace of test.news.pager ?
My block name is 'Block\Home|SaleList' , template is view\frontend\template\discountproduct.phtml

Comment: Sir i debug my code is not enter in block if condition .

    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>

this condition is not true if ($block->getPagerHtml())
why not getPagerHtml true ? 
please guide me little bit more . . . .

Comment: @@hafizumer replace it with your desired name.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I'm trying to implement this (https://uk.burberry.com/womens-bags/?locale=en_UK&ds_rl=1004120&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6YDiibSR5AIVhvdRCh1xdgVHEAAYASABEgKLzvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) type of collection, would your code help to implement this type of collection ?

Comment: @AasimGoriya this code is related to magento 2.

Comment: @QaisarSatti sorry it's my mistake, I didn't explain properly, Actually, my question is, I want to develop category collection with products and load more (multiple paginations on single page) as per provided URL in my Magento2 site, So that's why I have asked you that does your code will help me to develop multiple paginations on single page ? Any other suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: @AasimGoriya it will create a problem you can use it for single page pagination. it will work fine for others you have to change the URL parameter. but I am not sure of that.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Yeah I thought the same, that's why asked you for that, anyway thanks for your response, do you have any other idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: @AasimGoriya you can handle with ajax

Comment: @QaisarSatti Thanks, yes I'm trying to do it with AJAX.

Comment: @QaisarSatti How I can doe pagination with Ajax ?

Comment: Perfect Working for me.