# How to use setTemplate() in Custom modules _construct() magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

How to achieve the `setTemplate()` in the custom modules constructor?

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('Myfolder/filter.phtml');
}

protected function _toHtml() {
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Are we achieving the same in the layout file or how?

Answer (score 6):

I achieved this by adding the `$_template` variable

`protected $_template = 'Myfolder/filter.phtml';`

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Test extends Template
{

    protected $_template = 'Myfolder/filter.phtml';

}
```

example you can see

**vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\Block\Navigation\State.php**

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-set-block-template/)

Comment: Should we give Vendor_Module::Myfolder/filter.phtml? and how come you are using  $_template = 'test.phtml'; inside class? no need to use that $_template anywhere in the constructor?

Comment: i think it already referring the you module also in magento core i didn't see any module name with it. so my opinion  `Myfol‌​der/filter.phtml`

Comment: ok Qaisar, where im i supposed to use that $_template? in _construct() or where?

Comment: as i mention in my code you have add protected variable of $_template in class. just as i added the example

Comment: i tried directly in the phtml as <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">

Comment: @SachinS this is xml code don't run in phtml for calling in phtml need `<?php  echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct')
          ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
          ->toHtml(); ?>`

Comment: Sorry its a typo... it was supposed to be xml... "i tried directly in the layout xml as <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">"

Comment: this xml is not working?

Comment: its working now... need to know on how to get the pagination in my custom modules now as asked here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131896/add-pagination-for-magento-catalog-toolbar-in-custom-module-magento-2

Comment: @SachinS you are asking about toolbar i didn't work with yet so simple pager the solution is there and if you find this question helpful accept the answer