# Add Pagination for Magento Catalog Toolbar in custom module magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to override the pagination, sort by, Show per page in the phtml of magento2?

How to override the same in our custom module?

[image]

[image]

Need help in overriding the correct phtml and layout files!

This is what i tried!

Had overridden :
**Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php**

```
public function getPagerHtml()
{
   //as is
}
```

**Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <!-- <referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" >
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock> -->
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Vendor_Module::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
         </block>
         <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
             <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
         </action>
    </block>
</body>
</page>
```

But for this i only get the pagination and other controls as shown:

[image]

Comment: Any update @Qaisar Satti