# Magento 2 - Element with same id already exists

Tags: magento2, module, custom, pager

I'm trying to set the Magento 2 pager on my custom module, my custom module get the product collection and makes some special filters on the collection. I'm able to filter my products, but when I try to add the pager I get this error:

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Element with ID 'pairings.product.pager' already exists.

Here my block:

```
<?php namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block; class Filter extends \<Vendor>\<OtherCustomModule>\Block\ProductAbstract {

const ENTITY_TYPE = 'catalog_product';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_productCollection;

/**
 * Filter constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $modelCategory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $modelCategory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $priceHelper,
        $modelCategory,
        $data
    );
    $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
}

public function getFilteredProducts()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $productsFiltered = array();
    if (count($params)) {

        $collection = $this->_productCollection->create();
        $productsFiltered = $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $pageSize = 8;
        if (isset($params['limit'])) {
            $pageSize = $params['limit'];
            unset($params['limit']);
        }
        $page = 1;
        if (isset($params['page'])) {
            $page = $params['page'];
            unset($params['page']);
        }
        $ordersParam = array(
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'sorter' => 'asc'
        );
        if (isset($params['sort'])) {
            if ($params['sort'] == 'price_asc') {
                $ordersParam = array(
                    'attribute' => 'price',
                    'sorter' => 'asc'
                );
            } elseif ($params['sort'] == 'price_desc') {
                $ordersParam = array(
                    'attribute' => 'price',
                    'sorter' => 'desc'
                );
            }
            unset($params['sort']);
        }
        foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
            if ($key == 'prezzo') {
                $parts = explode(',', $param);
                $min = (isset($parts[0]) ? $parts[0] : 0);
                $max = (isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : 400);
                $productsFiltered = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gteq' => $min))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lteq' => $max));
            } else {
                $productsFiltered = $collection->addAttributeToFilter($key, array('in' => $param));
            }
        }
        $productsFiltered->setOrder($ordersParam['attribute'], $ordersParam['sorter']);
        $productsFiltered->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $productsFiltered->setCurPage($page);
    }

    return $productsFiltered;
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Abbinamenti'));

    if ($this->getFilteredProducts()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'pairings.product.pager'
        )->setAvailableLimit(array(8=>8,16=>16,24=>24,32=>32,40=>40))->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
            $this->getFilteredProducts()
        );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getFilteredProducts()->load();
    }

    return $this;
}

public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}}
```

As you can see my custom module extend an other custom module that extends `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`.

In my .phtml I use `getPagerHtml()` method to get the pager.

### EDIT

I followed this old post to create my paginator, but It doesn't work: [Old post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130405/how-to-add-pagination-on-custom-collection-magetno-2)

Comment: Can any one tell what exactly this error means?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I fixed it adding an if condition:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
   parent::_prepareLayout();
   $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Concept Sketch Requests'));

   if ($this->getRequestsCollection()) {
      $blockName = 'coneceptrequest.pager';
      $pager = null;
      if ($this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
          $pager = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)
            ->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5, 10=>10, 15=>15, 20=>20))
            ->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
              $this->getRequestsCollection()
            );
      } else {
          $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            $blockName
          )->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5, 10=>10, 15=>15, 20=>20))
          ->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
            $this->getRequestsCollection()
          );
      }
      $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
      $this->getRequestsCollection()->load();
   }
   return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `getBlock` instead of `createBlock`

```
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Abbinamenti'));

        if ($this->getFilteredProducts()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()
                      ->getBlock('pairings.product.pager')
                      ->setAvailableLimit(array(8=>8,16=>16,24=>24,32=>32,40=>40))
->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
                $this->getFilteredProducts()
            );
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getFilteredProducts()->load();
        }
```

Comment: I get `HTTP ERROR 500` in this way.

Comment: What is the error on the error log?

Comment: cache_invalidate: "invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false

Comment: What do you mean with load layout? I have run `cache:flush` command

Comment: That is not the php error, look inside you php error log

Comment: I don't have setted the php error log on my php.ini

Comment: ask your hosting provider where the php errors default or try looking inside your vhosts conf

Comment: Ok, but I tryed to put a `var_dump($pager->_toHtml()); die();` after your `getBlock()` and I get error with white page, while when I use `createBlock()` I get the paginator and It works, the problem is something with rendering of the block