# How to add pager limit in core file in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to add some condition for pager in order collection.

In Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History.php;

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getOrders()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager::class,
                'sales.order.history.pager'
            )->setCollection(
                $this->getOrders()
            );
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getOrders()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I need to add this in pager

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager::class,
                    'sales.order.history.pager'
                ) ->setAvailableLimit(array(4 => 4))
                  ->setShowPerPage(false)
                  ->setCollection(
                        $this->getOrders()
                    );
```

So, I have override this block file like

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getOrders()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager::class,
                'sales.order.history.pager'
            )->setAvailableLimit(array(4 => 4))
                ->setShowPerPage(false)
                ->setCollection(
                $this->getOrders()
            );
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getOrders()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): An
>   element with a "sales.order.history.pager" ID already exists.

How to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: why not override using preference?

Comment: I have tried this. but it throws 'sales.order.history.pager' already exists

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149065/magento-2-element-with-same-id-already-exists?answertab=active#tab-top can you check this